# Meaning of "Sod rebounded from the lid" in Camus' The Plague

Tags: sentence-meaning

In Camus book "the plague",  the narrator is describing burial ceremonies.so after placing coffin in the grave,There is sentence which I don't understand

> "No sooner had the priest begun to sprinkle holy water than the **first sod rebounded from the lid**".

I know sod is a part of turf.but how is it rebounded when priest sprinkle holy water. Is sod on the coffin so when water is sprinkled, it falls off. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as the priest started sprinkling the coffin with holy water, some other person started throwing sod upon the coffin in order to cover it with sod.

The sentence shows that the ceremony was conducted in a hasty manner.